# Which is the decision rule in a gda classifier?

Tags: bayesian, prediction, posterior, discriminant-analysis, generative-models

On the text book there is the following formula for the prediction rule, but I don’t understand where it comes from:

[image]

The textbooks says it had been derived from[image]

I suppose pi and theta are the parameters of the model but I really don’t get where the log comes from

Comment: What is $\pi$ in the first formula, and $\theta_c$?

Comment: it’s not specified, but I assume that they both are parameters of the model so they are a different way of writing teta from the second formula

Comment: Can you share the source?

Comment: Machine learning - a probabilistic approach by Kevin P.Murphy page 102

Comment: Also the page? In order to locate it.

Comment: page 102 first formula and at page 30 there’s the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter you're referring is about discriminant analysis with Gaussian mixtures, and $\mathbf{\pi}$ vector is the mixture probabilities, i.e. class priors. Also, $\theta_c$ represents all the parameters (i.e. mean vector and covariance matrix, and priors) for class $c$. We're interested in classifying a samples as best as we can, and in this framework, this is done through choosing the class maximizing the posterior: $$p(y=c|x,\theta)=\frac{p(x|y=c,\theta)p(y=c|\theta)}{p(x|\theta)}$$
while maximizing this expression wrt $c$, denominator has no effect and you can omit it. So, you maximize
$p(x|y=c,\theta)p(y=c|\theta)$. And you can also maximize the log of the expression since it's monotonically increasing. Also, considering that $p(x|y=c,\theta)=p(x|\theta_c)$ (because if class is given as $c$, we're only interested in parameters related to class $c$), and $p(y=c|\theta)=p(y=c|\pi)$ since probability of being class $c$ w/o data, i.e. prior, depends on only the prior probabilities and not mean/covariance of different mixture components.

So, the optimization objective becomes the following:
$$\log p(x|\theta_c) + \log p(y=c|\pi)$$
And you choose the argmax $c$ of it to decide the class of a given $x$.

Comment: Gosh thank you so much!

Comment: I did upvoted but it says that I haven’t enough reputation points to do that

Comment: with less than 15 points my vote is registered but not visible

Comment: Oh thanks, You can accept the answer by clicking the grey tick below the arrow pointing downwards.